# Better way to generate Postgresql covered index with SQLAlchemy and Alembic

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

Since Postgresql 11 covered index have been introduced. We create a covered index using `INCLUDE` keyword like this:

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(indexed_col_name) INCLUDE (covered_col_name);`
[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) the official postgresql doc for more details.

I have done some research on Google but did not find how to implement this feature with SQLAlchemy and include it in the migration file generated by Alembic. Any proposition, idea, doc link will be appreciated.

Comment: There generally isn't much point in a covering index.  They are useful if you want to declare the index unique on some prefix of the columns, or if you want to cover a column which is of a type which doesn't define ordering operators.  Otherwise, just include the extra column in the main body of the index `(indexed_col_name, covered_col_name)`

Comment: If including the column in the main body is sufficient, then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73528028/17676984) should help.

Comment: I want to use covered index to enable index only scan, covered column does not need to be part of the main index. Am not declaring unique constraints index but index on column used by `where` filter in order to speed up the `select`

Answer (score 4):

```
Index("my_index", table.c.x, postgresql_include=['y'])
```

It's in the postgres-specific part of the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-specific-index-options)

See also: [issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4458), [commit](https://gerrit.sqlalchemy.org/c/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/+/2204/14/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py#676)